# Get Specific Custom Field from Custom Post type by key

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching for this and took days but didn't find the solution anywhere. I am using a code to get the specific custom field value by key number (see below code) but I want to get the value of a custom field by key name for example key name is "post-code".

Note: **lead_custom_field** is a custom field.

```
<?php
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['lead_custom_field'];
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
    $a1 = unserialize( $value );
    echo '<td>'. $a1[1]['value'] . '</td>';
}
?>
```

Please help, I am stuck in this for so long.

Comment: This completely depends on how you are _storing_ the custom data.  Are you using the WP function [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)? Or writing the data directly? Or other?

Answer (score 2):

[`get_post_custom()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/) returns all of the custom fields associated with a post.

You can use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) which will return a single value by key.

The following will output the value of the your `lead_custom_field` custom field key.

```
var_dump( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'lead_custom_field', true ) );
```

It appears you are storing an multi-dimensional array inside `lead_custom_field`. You should consider restructuring your data to a more appropriate format like so:

```
array(
    'post-code' => 12345,
    'first-name' => 'John',
    'last-name' => 'Doe
)
```

Which would allow you to simply do:

```
$data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'lead_custom_field', true );
echo 'Post Code: '. $data['post-code'];
```

Without restructuring *how* you save that data, you'll need to keep using a loop of some kind since, based on our chat, you have:

- A key named "key" with a value of "post-code"
- A key named "value" with a value of "12345"

All inside an unnamed arrays. So you need to loop through *somehow* unless you fundamentally change how you store that data. Either in an array like I have above, or in separate custom fields.

Comment: Are you sure `$post_id` is currently defined in this scope and `post-code` is the key name with an appropriate value? What output does `var_dump( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post-code', true ) );` give you?

Comment: yes post id is defined as the above code is working. And your code gives this, bool(false)

Comment: ok I defined this `$post_id = get_the_ID();` `var_dump( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post-code', true ) );` now giving this `string(0) ""`

Comment: `bool(false)` means that the post ID is incorrect. `string(0) ""` means that the Custom Field Key "`post-code`" doesn't exist.

Comment: post id is correct now and post code exist in the Custom Field please see this `{s:3:"key";s:9:"post-code";s:5:"value";s:4:"3977";}`

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump( get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173437/discussion-between-xhynk-and-yasir-khan).

Answer (score -1):

One of my friend helped me in this he's a great php developer. Posting here as an answer if someone looking for this.

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
$my_custom_field = unserialize( $custom_fields['lead_custom_field'][0] );
$params = [];
foreach ($my_custom_field as $k) {
    $params[ $k["key"] ] = $k["value"];
}
echo '<td>' . $params["post-code"] . '</td>';
?>
```

Comment: This is the wrong / hard way to do it.... See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50938214/870729) for the right way.  Further, `get_post_custom` already returns `unserialized` data.  Lastly, when unserializing in WP, you should use the WP function [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize), which is safe, whereas unserialize may throw errors.

Comment: I needed a result and the above solution gave me the exact required result.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  My points are still all correct, even though it works for you.